# How to run magic command in jupyter lab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab

I am trying to run magic commmands in jupyter lab which I recently installed with some debugger extension from this link:

https://github.com/jupyterlab/debugger

When I run this command:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint

 #A function to simulate one million dice throws.

def one_million_dice():
   return randint(low=1, high=7, size=1000000)
 
%%time
throws = one_million_dice()
mean = np.mean(throws)
```

Error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SyntaxError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\Users\****\Anaconda3\envs\jupyterlab-debugger\lib\ast.py, in parse:
Line 35:    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic functions should be put in a single cell.
Try:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint

 #A function to simulate one million dice throws.

def one_million_dice():
   return randint(low=1, high=7, size=1000000)
```

Move to the next cell

```
%%time
throws = one_million_dice()
mean = np.mean(throws)
>>Wall time: 40.9 ms
```

Comment: Check the indent of return once.

Comment: Indent is fine. The error pops up when I run second part of code.

Comment: Have you added the entire traceback to the question?

Comment: JUpyter lab gives me only this output. How to check the entire error.?